# buildbot - how to fill project field in forcebuild form

Tags: field, project, buildbot

I want to fill project field with list of projects . User will select one of the project and start Forcebuild. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite original templates.

You can user below code in master.cfg;

```
import jinja2

loader = [
    jinja2.FileSystemLoader("YOUR_TEMPLATES_PATH"),
]
c['status'].append(html.WebStatus(http_port=8080, authz=authz_cfg, jinja_loaders=loader))
```